# Does Blender 2.79 fully support 3D mouse?

Tags: 3d-mouse

Considering purchasing a 3D mouse, but I'm unsure (even after extensive Googling) as to whether or not Blender is fully compatible. Sculpt mode is apparently a yes, as is Object mode (please correct me if I'm wrong!), but what about Edit mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Blender is fully compatible. I use a 3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator with Blender both in Windows and OS X daily. It works great in all 3D views/modes but also in (for example) the Node Editor where you can pan around and zoom in/out.

Note: I haven't used the buttons much since there are only two on this particular model, but for navigating around it is really a time saver.

Comment: Do you end up having to lift your hand off it all the time to use keyboard shortcuts? Does your hand rest on the keyboard most of the time? I am worried that this would be awkward and negate any benefits of the 3d mouse...

Comment: If anyone is wondering what settings to get their 3D Space Mouse working reasonably well, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119101/use-3d-mouse-in-blender?rq=1