# Use 3D mouse in Blender

Tags: 3d-mouse

I'm quite big on using my 3Dconnexion SpaceMouse (I use it all the time for CAD work), but using it with Blender isn't exactly plug 'n play. I can get some but not all axes of rotation to work and on the internet I can only find information that seems either outdated or somehow irrelevant. Help!

EDIT: I use Windows 10, and a wireless 3DConnexion SpaceNavigator. When I plug it in, the following 4 DOF axes work:

zoom in/out

shift left/right

shift up/down

rotate towards/away (from my perspective)

The problem is with the other 2 DOF axes: rotate sideways (from my perspective) and rotate about the object's long axis (my best description: if you model a beer bottle and rotate it about it's long axis you won't actually see something rotate, that's the axis I mean :P).

Now, according to one source (https://www.3dconnexion.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1497&start=30) the solution may be in: user preferences -> input -> 3D-view -> 3D-view (Global) -> NDOF Orbit/Pan/Move
but after a short attempt to make that work I concluded I didn't really understand how to do that.[image: Blender's user pref -> 3D view panel]

Hope that helps more!

Cheers,
Caspar

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac? What did you get to work and what links did you use?

Comment: rob, wanna get back on this?

Comment: sorry, I do not have any expertise in this area and was just hoping to kick start some one who does. If you believe it is a bug then you should report it to the devs. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten about 3/4 of the way there on this. I can move in every axis. However, you have to hold shift to Pan. While panning, you can't orbit. It's quite frustrating, but it's better than nothing, I suppose. Do the following:

Reverse all axes and crank them up to max in the 3DConnexion software.[image: screenshot]

I have the following settings in Blender:

[image]