# Blender 2.8 and 3DConnexion's 3D mice

Tags: 3d-view, hardware, 3d-mouse

It seems that the new blender 2.8 now takes its NDOF parameters from 3DConnexion's settings via their SDK,.. and no longer configurable through preferences>input>NDOF.  This is all good in that you can invert axes and control sensitivity and all via 3DConnexion,..  but unlike Maya/NX etc, you cannot select between object and camera mode.  And no permutation of setting's in Blenders preferences or inverting any combination of axes will get you to Object mode.  This is well explained in

- https://buijs.pro/using-3d-mouse-blender-mac/ and 3DConnexion's response can be found in
- [Blender 3D Space mouse settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137082/blender-3d-space-mouse-settings)

...and here where 3DConnexion blames Blender...

- https://www.3dconnexion.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38146

I think the SDK was utilized in the new Blender 2.8+ but how do I get object mode?  I worry that because NDOF keymap is "Orbit and Zoom" (no pan), perhaps Blender devs knew it wasn't that straightforward to implement.  However, it worked back in 2.7 with a plug-in.  Question is, should I look out for object mode in the future or revert to and earlier version of Blender?